# How can i stop someone from spamming my console using the write command in linux

Tags: linux, unix

How can I block someone from spamming by console using the "write" command in unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command `mesg n`. Preferably, add it to your .bashrc or equivalent so it runs when you start up.

Answer (score 1):

In your console, type:

```
mesg n
```

For more information, read the manual pages (`man mesg`).